# do i have to update my iphone (to the latest version) to connect it with the latest version of xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iPhone 7 (on iOS 10.3.3) and I don't want to update it to iOS 11 but my Xcode version is 9.2 (9C40b). Can I run apps on my iPhone from xcode or do I have to install iOS 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to update iOS on your iPhone to use it with Xcode 9.2 (or anything newer).

You just need to ensure that your iOS app has a Deployment Target of iOS 10.3 or earlier so you can run the app on your iPhone.

The Deployment Target defines the earlier version of iOS you wish to support.

Keep this in mind: within certain limits, you can use newer Tools to work with older devices but you can't use older tools with newer devices.